# How should I cope with the 16TiB limit on linux software RAID (md)?

Tags: linux, mdadm, software-raid

I have used a RAID6 based on partitions on 2TB disks for around 10 years, now. Which I have extended multiple times up to around 12TB by adding disks a few times.

With the time, I have progressively replaced my failing disks with 4TB ones in order to extend it to 3.5TiB partitions and then remove the disks in excess ('t would be sooo nice to be able to close this computer case at some time ;-p X-D)

However, it appears to be a 16TiB limit on md RAIDs. When I tried grow it to --size=max, mdadm and /proc/mdstat reported having grown my units to 3663892.5MiB and my whole RAID space to 21983355MiB. However, trying to read from the disk only allowed me to access 5206139MiB = 21983355MiB - 16TiB (Here I tried to read last MiB and next and I can only read #5206138).

```
root@nas:~# dd if=/dev/md0 bs=1M skip=5206138 of=/dev/null count=2 
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1,0 MB) copied, 0.00472265 s, 222 MB/s
```

Searching for information about this limit didn't yield much information. Do you know more about how to manage this problem ?

EDIT: This problem is NOT about filesystem size, but about the bare unpartitionned RAID space (and btw, my raid version is 1.2)

EDIT2 : I wonder if the problem might not be related with my still using an old 32 bits Kernel.

Comment: mdadm had a 2T limit (per member drive) with 0.90 metadata. ext4 had an issue growing past 16T. not sure which one you are referring to. either limit should no longer apply on a modern installation but might still affect embedded devices (like old dedicated NAS devices).

Comment: My raid is 1.2 version, and I have no issue with the ext4 filesystem. I have no plans to extend it over 16TiB

Comment: You should seriously consider dumping the 32 bit system, support for 32 bit is growing weaker by the year since no devs really use it, except on ARM. Note you have one of two problems, either you have a 32 bit cpu, which is a problem, or you are running  a 32 bit kernel on 64 bit cpu, which is also a problem and almost certainly a mistake you should correct.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1532 also depends on which linux you are using, as you can see, older redhats did in fact have a  16TB limit on ext4 fs. You need to list the relevant details, not just generics about what you'd like to be doing.

Comment: @lizard the OP says this question isn't about filesystem sizes

Comment: indeed. I have added the test which shows the failure. @Lizardx, I have considered changing it for years, now. but every time you change things you add risks of something going awry.

Comment: Camion, the risks for using  no longer maintained software or operating systems is higher, particularly when it comes to very old 32 bit stuff. It's best to bite the bullet, switch to 64 bit, use a distribution that supports distribution upgrades reliably, then never have an issue like this again.

Comment: roaima, you're read this after he updated it, I read it before, and it was basically what a  I said, a legacy 32 bit os limiting capacities.

Comment: One of the nice side of Linux is that i can be used on old computers. It would be sad if 32bits kernels would suddenly have to be thrown to oblivion. But well, indeed, it's true that I didn't expect it to limit the size of my RAID. It might be a bug, in fact.

Comment: One of the nice side of Linux is that it can be used on old computers. It would be sad if 32bits kernels would suddenly have to be thrown to oblivion. But well, indeed, it's true that I didn't expect it to limit the size of my RAID. It looks like it was signaled as a bug 5 years ago and never solved, in fact (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113391).

Answer (score 0):

OK. It appears that the problem came from my server still using an old distribution with a 32bits kernel. Booting it from a more recent OS solved it.

```
nas ~ # cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid6 sdf40[9] sdc48[8](S) sdb42[14] sdd46[15] sda41[10] sdi45[13] sde43[12] sdh47[16] sdg44[11]
      22510955520 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      [===========>.........]  resync = 57.2% (2146318848/3751825920) finish=441.6min speed=60584K/sec
      bitmap: 7/14 pages [28KB], 131072KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

nas ~ # dd if=/dev/md0 bs=1K skip=22510955519 of=/dev/null count=2
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1024 bytes (1.0 kB, 1.0 KiB) copied, 0.0198348 s, 51.6 kB/s
```

Comment: I fell into this trap as well. In my case, the kernel successfully assembled a 55TB raid volume and lsblk etc. all listed it correctly, but trying to read anythingt beyond about 49TB returned end-of-file.